# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin while trying to access a REMOTE XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am getting the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://backend.deviantart.com/rss.xml?q=favby%3Aseventhfairy%2F52610498&type=deviation. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

I have searched a lot, all the answers suggest trying to use a remote server, the file i'm trying to access is already online not on my machine

Here is my piece of ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://backend.deviantart.com/rss.xml?q=favby%3Aseventhfairy%2F52610498&type=deviation",
        //url: "rss.xml",
        async: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can't access file from different domain, you need to access that file from your own domain, where you are running this script

Comment: I am running the script on my PC, and I need to get the feed from another website, in this case DeviantArt. I don't know what to do

Comment: and actually the links you guys posted do not solve my problem at all